# bash script to extract string from last output line

Tags: bash, text-processing

This bash script tries to get the string "ami-774b7314" from the output of the following command so that it can be used as input to another command in the same script:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --region ap-southeast-2 --owners amazon --output text --query 'Images[].{A1name:Name,A2id:ImageId}' --filters Name=is-public,Values=true,Name=name,Values=amzn-ami-*.*.*-amazon-ecs-optimized | sort

amzn-ami-2016.03.i-amazon-ecs-optimized ami-22a49541
amzn-ami-2016.03.j-amazon-ecs-optimized ami-862211e5
amzn-ami-2016.09.a-amazon-ecs-optimized ami-73407d10
amzn-ami-2016.09.b-amazon-ecs-optimized ami-5781be34
amzn-ami-2016.09.c-amazon-ecs-optimized ami-774b7314 <===== this line
```

and to verify it is in the format ami-and-a-mix-of-alphanumeric else echo "bad string" and exit the script

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tail` command may be used for this. It gives you the last few (10 by default) lines of input as output (the "tail" of it).

With the `-n` flag you may specify exactly how much of the tail you'd like to have:

```
aws ec2 ... | sort | tail -n 1
```

To verify that it follows the right format, you may do

```
line="$( aws ec2 ... | sort | tail -n 1 )"

if [[ ! "$line" =~ ^amzn-ami-[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[a-z]-amazon-ecs-optimized\ ami-[0-9a-z]{8}$ ]]; then
    echo "bad string"
    exit 1
fi
```

If you only want *the last bit* of the last line, use `cut` to cut it out:

```
line="$( aws ec2 ... | sort | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 )"
```

The `-d ' ' -f 2` bit says "use space as the field delimiter and give me the second field".

Then the regular expression becomes shorter too:

```
if [[ ! "$line" =~ ^ami-[0-9a-z]{8}$ ]]; then
    echo "bad string"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `cut -d ' ' -f 2` is still giving the whole line. I also tried `-d ' ' -f 1` for no avail. it seams like the space delimiter is not working with this line... any idea?

Comment: @FredJ. "Works for me". I copied your example data into a file and used it as it was. Is there a tab there maybe?

Comment: @FredJ. If there's a tab, change `-d ' '` to `-d $'\t'`.